# Add Checkbox to header of gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I have following gridview:

[image]

I wanted to put checkbox to header of this grid, means below or besides Maths,Physics,Chemistry,Biology Header Text.

**Code for Grid:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="GvSearch" runat="server" CellPadding ="3"
                                Width="100%" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
           <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblCity" runat="server"  Text='<%# Bind("City") %>' ></asp:Label>
                       <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkCity" runat="server" />
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Maths">

                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblMaths" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Maths") %>'></asp:Label>

                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Physics">

                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblPhysics" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Physics") %>'></asp:Label>

                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Chemistry">

                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblChemistry" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Chemistry") %>'></asp:Label>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
               <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Biology">
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblBio" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Biology") %>'></asp:Label>
                   </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
         </asp:GridView>
```

I tried adding it as:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Physics">
                   <HeaderTemplate>
                   <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkCity" runat="server" />
                   </HeaderTemplate>
                   <ItemTemplate>
                       <asp:Label ID="lblPhysics" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Physics") %>'></asp:Label>

                   </ItemTemplate>
```

But this didnt worked.

Please help me to add checkbox to header of gridview.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure, but I think the `HeaderText` property in `TemplateField` might be causing problems with the `HeaderTemplate`.  Looking at a code sample on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.headertemplate.aspx), they don't use `HeaderText` when using the `HeaderTemplate`.  Try something like this (not tested):

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="ChkCity" Text="Physics" runat="server" />
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        ....
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Its rubbing my header text, i want headertext also

Comment: @M.N.S. - You set the text in the `CheckBox` control using the `Text` property.  Is that not working (i.e., the Text isn't showing up)?

Comment: ohh,let me try that one