# How can I add check box inside grid view columns?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I want to add check box inside grid view.But I don't want to add the check box in rows, I want to add the check box in column header.
Thank You

I want get the output like given below..

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939172/add-checkbox-to-header-of-gridview

Comment: @KiranHegde I think you dont get my question!? "I want to add check box in column headers, not in rows"

Comment: May be I did not understand, can you explain. I thought you want to add checkbox on column header.

Comment: @KiranHegde See above given image. I need an out put like that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Checkbox HeaderTemplate field in GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <Columns>
               <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width="40px">
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkboxSelectAll" runat="server" onclick="CheckAllEmp(this);" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" />
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkEmp" runat="server"></asp:CheckBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

For further details you can refer to these sites: [site1](http://www.dotnetgallery.com/kb/resource18-Gridview-header-checkbox-select-and-deselect-all-rows-using-client-side-Jav.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 <columns>
          <asp:templatefield>            
            <itemtemplate>
              <%#Eval("fname")%>  
            </itemtemplate>
            <headertemplate>
              <asp:checkbox id="ShowAllCheckBox"              
                checked="True"
                runat="server"/>
            </headertemplate>
          </asp:templatefield>                      
        </columns>
```

Hope this helps you